# Entity Framework Core return all data if filter value is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core-2.2

I would like to know if it is possible on a where clause to just return all data when the filtered value is null.

I have a ViewModel with search parameters, if they are null i just want all the data to be returned, reason is to avoid repeating code using if clauses which looks dirty due to the null checking.

Here is my method

```
public void OnPost()
{
    if (POEViewModel.ReferenciaId != null)
    {
        POE = _context.Componentes
               .Include(c => c.Registo)
               .ThenInclude(r => r.Celula)
               .Where(c =>
                 c.Registo.ReferenciaId == POEViewModel.ReferenciaId &&
                 c.Registo.DataInicioTurno >= POEViewModel.DataInicio && c.Registo.DataInicioTurno <= POEViewModel.DataFim)
               .OrderByDescending(c => c.Id)
               .ToList();
    }
    else if (POEViewModel.Operador != null)
    {
        POE = _context.Componentes
               .Include(c => c.Registo)
               .ThenInclude(r => r.Celula)
               .Where(c =>
                 c.Registo.DataInicioTurno >= POEViewModel.DataInicio && c.Registo.DataInicioTurno <= POEViewModel.DataFim &&
                 c.Registo.Operador == POEViewModel.Operador)
               .OrderByDescending(c => c.Id)
               .ToList();
    }
    else if (POEViewModel.ReferenciaId != null && POEViewModel.Operador != null)
    {
        POE = _context.Componentes
               .Include(c => c.Registo)
               .ThenInclude(r => r.Celula)
               .Where(c =>
                 c.Registo.ReferenciaId == POEViewModel.ReferenciaId &&
                 c.Registo.DataInicioTurno >= POEViewModel.DataInicio && c.Registo.DataInicioTurno <= POEViewModel.DataFim &&
                 c.Registo.Operador == POEViewModel.Operador)
               .OrderByDescending(c => c.Id)
               .ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        POE = _context.Componentes
              .Include(c => c.Registo)
              .ThenInclude(r => r.Celula)
              .Where(c =>
                c.Registo.DataInicioTurno >= POEViewModel.DataInicio && c.Registo.DataInicioTurno <= POEViewModel.DataFim)
              .OrderByDescending(c => c.Id)
              .ToList();
    }

    ViewData["ReferenciaId"] = new SelectList(_context.Referencias, "Id", "Nome");
}
```

It might be a bit hard on the foreign keys cause they only accept integers to come up with a general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `null check` inside `Where`:

```
POE = _context.Componentes
    .Include(c => c.Registo).ThenInclude(r => r.Celula)
    .Where(c =>
        // Check for null before equality
        (POEViewModel.ReferenciaId == null || c.Registo.ReferenciaId == POEViewModel.ReferenciaId) &&
        // Check for null before equality
        (POEViewModel.Operador == null || c.Registo.Operador == POEViewModel.Operador) &&
        c.Registo.DataInicioTurno >= POEViewModel.DataInicio && 
        c.Registo.DataInicioTurno <= POEViewModel.DataFim)
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.Id)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks I picked yours because it even commented. I like this clean approach!

Answer (score 1):

You can construct your predicate beforehand:

```
public void OnPost()
{
    Expression<Func<Component, bool>> filter = c => 
        (POEViewModel.ReferenciaId != null ? c.Registo.ReferenciaId == POEViewModel.ReferenciaId : true) &&
        (POEViewModel.Operador != null ? c.Registo.Operador == POEViewModel.Operador : true);   

    POE = _context.Componentes
          .Include(c => c.Registo)
          .ThenInclude(r => r.Celula)
          .Where(filter)
          .Where(c =>
            c.Registo.DataInicioTurno >= POEViewModel.DataInicio && c.Registo.DataInicioTurno <= POEViewModel.DataFim)
          .OrderByDescending(c => c.Id)
          .ToList();

    ViewData["ReferenciaId"] = new SelectList(_context.Referencias, "Id", "Nome");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can then mix the `null` checking with a `||` operator like this

```
POE = _context.Componentes
               .Include(c => c.Registo)
               .ThenInclude(r => r.Celula)
               .Where(c =>
                 (POEViewModel.ReferenciaId==null || 
                  c.Registo.ReferenciaId == POEViewModel.ReferenciaId) &&
                 (POEViewModel.DataInicio==null||c.Registo.DataInicioTurno >= POEViewModel.DataInicio)
                 && 
                (POEViewModel.DataFim==null||c.Registo.DataInicioTurno <= POEViewModel.DataFim))
               .OrderByDescending(c => c.Id)
               .ToList();
```

There is a `.HasValue` property that returns a boolean and can help you check if your parameter has a or not. this applies to nullable types only. So instead of `POEViewModel.DataInicio==null` you can write `POEViewModel.DataInicio.HasValue`